# Including external source code in the project for debugging

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, opc-ua

I'm working with `UA-.NetStandard-Sample` project and I would like to be able to debug the code that is implemented from the `nuget packages` and, if needed, make some changes in it. In order to do so I would like to include the source code from `UA-.NetStandard` Libraries as a reference to this project but I'm not really experienced working with `.Net` and `C#` and I could use some help. I'm working in Visual Studio 2017.

Does anyone have any advices on the most simple way how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: take a look at [source link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/). However, even with this there is not as nice debugging experience as local projects.

Answer (score 0):

As JonasH mentioned in their comment to your question, SourceLink can help, but it requires the package author to have set things up correctly. If they didn't it won't help you. It's also only for debugging, if you need to make changes, it also won't help.

This technique to make changes depends on the project you want to debug and improve being simple to build (no weird custom scripts or environment needed). But as long as that's the case, what I do is:

1. clone the repo next to mine. For example, I have `c:\src\MyRepo` and `c:\src\TheLibrary`.
2. Temporarily change any `<PackageReference Include="TheLibrary" Version="1.2.3" />` to `<ProjectReference Include="..\..\TheLibrary\path\to\TheLibrary.csproj" />`

   - If you use Visual Studio, temporarily adding TheLibrary to your solution helps improve the development experience
3. Debug and develop the projects as if they're in the same solution.
4. When you finish your development, commit, push and create a PR for TheLibrary. Since you didn't do any temporary changes in this repo, there isn't anything extra to do
5. Wait until TheLibrary merges your PR and a new package version is published.
6. Undo the temporary changes you made in step 2, and increase the package version to the one published in step 5.
7. Commit and create PR for your repo that started this whole effort.

If the library is developed/owned by someone else, step 5, waiting for them to publish a new version of the package with your changes, might take a long time. If this is unacceptable for your scenario, then the "easiest" solution is to fork the library, change the package name, and use your fork until the upstream author accepts your changes and publishes a new package version.

I recommend against having a private build of the library with your changes, but keeping the original package id, because NuGet assumes that packages are globally unique and immutable. If the package owner ends up creating a package with the same version that you used with your private fixes, you might find that your local and/or CI builds have weird behaviour, since there will be packages with the same id and version, but different contents, and which one gets used in a specific build depends on machine state, nuget source configuration, network & server speed. Non-deterministic builds are a bad place to be in.